# Django Admin filter_horizontal is not working

Tags: django, django-admin

I cannot set filter horizontal

```
admin.py
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('position',)
    filter_horizontal = ('key', )
admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)


models.py
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Position", null=True)
    key = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword, blank=True, verbose_name=u"Schlagworte")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
```

Can someone point me to my issue here?

Edit:
The widget does not show up.
No server side errors.
I get an JS error that I cannot interpret:

```
GET http://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/forton/http_headers_1.js 
(anonymous function) @ VM2228:1
(anonymous function) @ VM2228:1
```

Comment: Not working? Do you've got an error? Does the server not start? Is the widget not displayed? What does your browsers developer tools console say?

Comment: added more refined error description.